# HTML5 date input field in Chrome ignores twig formatting?

Tags: datetime

Im sorry, as I was formulating this question I discovered the answer. Chrome only accepts dates in ISO format (the accepted format for Chrome Date field is YYYY-MM-DD). So use:

```
<input type="date" name="date" value="{{ "now"|date("Y-m-d") }}" />
```

...which now looks aweful in Firefox, and not to mention the Date Picker issues.

Comment: Hey Eli, welcome to Craft Stack Exchange! It looks like you've mixed your answer in with your question... that's not really good protocol. It's possible to provide an answer to your own question (though your rep points may currently be too low for that). Once you've got enough rep, I'd recommend splitting up your "question" and "answer", in order to properly fit the expected format of SE. Otherwise, this question may end up getting closed as "Not a question". Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. I was just surpirsed at how the answer wasnt in this or your Google forum so decided to keep the question to help others.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the contribution! Just trying to make sure that the typical Question + Answer format is applied.

Comment: Eli... Please adjust this question so it's formatted as a question and answer to fit the StackExchange format.